# Pass parameters to passed-in block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to pass a block to a function, and then call that block with some additional parameters as follows:

```
def foo(&block)
  some_array = (1..3).to_a
  x = 7 # Simplified
  result = some_array.map &block # Need some way to pass in 'x' here
end

def a_usage_that_works
  foo do |value|
    value
  end
end

def a_usage_that_doesnt_work
  foo do |value, x|
    x # How do I pass in x?
  end
end

# rspec to demonstrate problem / required result
describe "spike" do
  it "works" do
    a_usage_that_works.should == [1,2,3]
  end
  it "doesn't work" do
    a_usage_that_doesnt_work.should == [7, 7, 7]
  end
end
```

How can I pass in the additional parameter to the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another block and call first one from it.

```
def foo(&block)
  some_array = (1..3).to_a
  x = 7 # Simplified
  result = some_array.map {|elem| block.call(elem, x)}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass to the block by yielding to it.

```
def foo(&block)
  some_array = [1,2,3]
  x = 7
  some_array.map{|el| yield el, x}
end

p foo{|p1, p2| p2} #=>[7,7,7]
p foo{|p1, p2| p1} #=>[1,2,3]
```

Comment: This doesn't pass the tests provided.  It throws away the values from `some_array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) to generate a simplified function:

Let's assume that the block we pass to `foo` will accept `value, x`.

Naive strategy, using an inline-defined `x`:

```
def foo(&block)
  some_array = (1..3).to_a
  x = 7
  simple_func = proc {|value| block.call(value, x) }
  result = some_array.map &simple_func
end
```

Strategy using separation of concerns:

```
def get_simple_func(block)
  # This assumes x won't change per iteration.
  # If it can change, you can move the calculation inside the proc.
  # Moving it inside also allows the calculation to depend on "value", in case you want that.
  x = complex_calculation_for_x()
  proc {|value| block.call(value, x) }
end

def foo(&block)
  some_array = (1..3).to_a
  simple_func = get_simple_func(block)
  result = some_array.map &simple_func
end
```

Obviously you shouldn't use this when `x` is a literal value because it would be over-engineering. But as the calculation of `x` becomes more complex, separating it out makes the code more readable. Also, `foo` can focus on the specific task of applying the function to `some_array`.